# How to `docker cp` ssh key to docker container before its entrypoint is executed

Tags: docker, docker-stack, docker-cp

Say I have this right now:

```
docker run -v /root/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro my_image
```

and the ENTRYPOINT for the above image is:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "foo"]
```

instead I want to do something like this:

```bsh
docker run -d --name c my_image   # problem: this will likely exit early :(
docker cp /root/.ssh c:/root/.ssh
docker exec c echo foo
```

the problem is: how do I keep the container alive so that it waits for me to copy the ssh key into it and then run the `echo foo` command?

Maybe I can keep it alive by telling it to wait for stdin? But how exactly?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?  It seems as if mounting the key into the image using `-v` is the simplest solution, and it's not clear why you're looking for an alternative. In general, no, you can't somehow copy something into the container before the entrypoint executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need first to create the container:

```
docker create my_image
```

then Copy the files:

```
 docker cp /root/.ssh MY_CREATED_CON:/root/.ssh
```

start the container normally:

```
docker start MY_CREATED_CON
```